# use-package - load package depending on the OS username

Tags: use-package, java, system-environment

I am not a Java guy at all, but I mess with it quite often for university reasons. I have used [this](http://www.goldsborough.me/emacs,/java/2016/02/24/22-54-16-setting_up_emacs_for_java_development/) awesome post by [peter goldsborough](https://github.com/goldsborough) to set up eclim. Which is nice! But this also requires a lot of setup in order to work. I have also use this awesome package called [maghanada](https://github.com/mopemope/meghanada-emacs) to set up a cool java environment that is much more portable but lacks refactoring features.

I wish I could load eclim, if my current username is `cescoferraro`, meaning I am on one of my machines. And load meghanada if I am somewhere else where I am usually just an id number like `34252354`, and probably wont have neither time nor permission enough to perform a eclim installation.

```
(use-package eclim :ensure t :if (not(equals os/username "cescoferraro")) :config (progn (...)))
(use-package mehganada :ensure t :if (equals os/username "cescoferraro") :config (progn (...)))
```

Comment: Are you looking for `user-login-name`?

Comment: You can also retrieve environment variables, e.g. `(getenv "USERNAME")`  (or some other env variable available on your OS). But I think `user-login-name` is looking for these same variables and is a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will give it a go asap. I am a emacs newbie

Comment: Actually the best way would be to check if you have eclim installed, then your config will automagically work regardless of username. Something like `(find-executable "eclimd")`.

Comment: Good point. The use-package config would just be `:if (executable-find "eclimd")`. @npostavs -- if you put your two suggestions in an answer I think it could be accepted.

Comment: i dont keep the eclimd executable under path. I am setting it conditionally depending on the os. https://github.com/cescoferraro/dotfiles/blob/master/src/emacs.d/configuration.org#eclim I ended up using (string-match-p (regexp-quote "cesco") user-login-name) cause my username at my osxmachine is just cesco

Comment: does anyone care to answer the question? use-login-name nails it